# How can I put laravel database queries into an indexed php array?

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

At the moment I have this:

```
$products = Product::whereIn('seller_id', $ids)->orderBy('price','desc')->limit(24)->get();
```

And then in the relevant views folder it just displays as this:

```
@foreach($products as product)
```

However I want to put it in an indexed array so that I can then style the products displayed in a grid layout.

Comment: what this means `However I want to put it in an indexed array so that I can then style the products displayed in a grid layout. `

Comment: something like this ? `@foreach($products as $key => $product)` ?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is display the products in a 3x3 grid on the views page and I think it would be easier to do so by having it in an indexed array and using loops. Would I still be able to index it using your way? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach ($products->chunk(3) as $items)
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($items as $product)
            <div class="col">
                {{ $product->price }}
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

if $products count is 9, it will show

```
|price | price | price|
|price | price | price|
|price | price | price|
```

if $products count is 5, it will show

```
|price | price | price|
|price | price |
```

so in your case, limit(24) will show row x 8 (each row has 3 column)

Answer (score 2):

you could try this:

```
$products = Product::whereIn('seller_id', $ids)->orderBy('price','desc')->limit(24)->get(); 
$products->toArray();
```

Comment: So by using this toArray();, I'll be able to access it by indexing it like $products[3] for example?

Comment: yes, you need only save the result into another variable for example: $productsArr = $products->toArray();

Comment: So then when I'm trying to loop through it, it will be $productsArr[loop index] that is in the loop correct?

Comment: You don't need to call `toArray()` to be able to access an item by its index i.e. `$products[0]` will work anyway.

Comment: But the default in Laravel is to put it in an associative array, not an indexed one.

Comment: @HamishGibson calling `get()` returns a collection of Eloquent object. Eloquent itself extends ArrayAccess and some other classes that ensures you can do virtually everything with it as though it is an array. So you can access it by index after returning.